# Using jdbcTemplate, what is a simple query I can do to test for connectivity?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm creating a simple health check page that ensures my application can connect to mysql.

I'm using jdbctemplate, what query do you suggest I perform that will not throw an error if the table is empty or anything, just something that ensures my spring app can connect to the database.

Comment: i would recommend one that doesn't hit every record of a table.  for instance, in oracle, you could do 'select 1 from dual' or in mySQL something like 'select 1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `select 1 from my_table`

Comment: using what jdbctemplate method?  it seems many throw exceptions if it returns no row.

Comment: Presumably the execute or query method.  Are you asking for help figuring out how to use jdbctemplate?

Comment: jdigital just making sure as you don't want a healthcheck page erroring out for no reason.

Comment: If table does not exist then this will throw and exception. Try the answer which I posted that may help you to check the connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) col FROM dual WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: Note that this would be the test query for and Oracle database (we know this because it's `FROM Dual`). Most other databases you would use `SELECT 1`.